# php - variable iteration in function

Tags: php, function

I wanted to have a result like this

```
50+2+2+2+2 = 58
```

But I'm getting these kind of result

```
50
2
2
2
2
```

these are my codes.

```
<?php

$height = 50;

echo $height;

function hey($x)
{
    return $height += $x;
}


$i = 4;

while($i != 0)
{
    echo "<br>".hey(2);

    $i--;
}

?>
```

Please take note that the location of my variable and loop must be and really meant at that position.

what do i need to change on my code. I am new in using php functions.
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `global` variable like this try:

```
function hey($x)
{
    global $height;
    return $height += $x;
}
```

And print the variable height only after the called function.
If you don't put `global` before the variable inside the function it the seems that you create a new variable inside your function. With global you tell to the server to take the variable that you have created outside the function

Comment: This is a good answer in this scenario, but I would generally avoid the use of `global` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

In this function:

```
function hey($x)
{
    return $height += $x;
}
```

`$height` is not in scope, so it is undefined. You should pass it in:

```
function hey($x, $height)
{
    return $height += $x;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
hey(2, $height);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is scope problem :

```
function hey($x)
{
    global $height;
    return $height += $x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
global $height;
```

then

```
while($i != 0)
{
    echo "+".hey(2);

    $i--;
}

echo "=" . $height;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand that you want, but if you need output like that, please try this code..

br mean go to bottom, so I delete it.

```
<?php
    $height = 50;

    echo $height;

    function hey($x)
    {

        echo " + $x";

        return $x;

    }

    $i = 4;

    while($i != 0)
    {
        $height += hey(2);

        $i--;
    }

    echo " = $height";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is online demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6h1-x5z

```
    <?php
        function getResult($height = 50, $increment = 2, $times = 4){
         echo $height."+";
         $total = 0;
         for ($i = 0; $i < $times; $i++){
            $total += $increment;     
          if ($i != ($times-1)){
           echo $increment."+";
          }
          else{
           echo $increment." = ".($height+$total);
          }          
         }      
        }    
        //usage
        getResult(50,2,4);
//The print out: 50+2+2+2+2 = 58
    ?>
```